# how to retrieve facebook friends list in react native app

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, authentication, native

I'm trying to retrieve all user's friends and render them in a list view using facebook graph request.

`const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
      '/me',
         {
           parameters: {
               fields: {
                        string: 'email, name, first_name, middle_name, 
                 last_name, picture.type(large), cover, birthday, location, friends'
                    }
                }
            },
            this._responseInfoCallback
        );`

Comment: What is the response you are getting from the call? Are you getting any error? if any, please tell

Comment: I am getting name, email etc, when i console log, but when i console.log friends i get undefined error. I didn't find any means to check whether friends list is availabe

Answer (score 2):

Facebook doesn't allow you to access your full friends list anymore since API 2.0, just those who also use your app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends.

For further reference you can also check the post [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

If you still have any queries please let me know. :)

**EDIT**

You can get the list of friends of the user which are not using this app with the api call given below:-

> https://graph.facebook.com/' + facebookUserId +
>   '/invitable_friends?access_token=' + userToken

and then inside the callback of the above api call you can make a new api call and get the list of users friends which are using the app with the call given below:-

> https://graph.facebook.com/' + facebookUserId + '/friends?access_token=' + userToken

and then you can concat the result of both the api calls and get the list of all the friends of the user as below:-

> let allFriends = firstApiResponseArray.concat(SecondApiResponseArray)

Now **allFriends** will give the list of all the friends of the user. I hope this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: ok thanks let me find out my mistake then!!

Comment: If you are using an app then you can get all the friends who are using your app and the one who are not using your app.

Comment: In my app, I want to let users login with their facebook and as soon as they login, I want to populate like (users list of friends, choose a random friend....).

Comment: @AnilHitang I have edited the answer please check. This is what you are looking for. I just checked this and it will give you the desired output.

Comment: I am using GraphRequest from facebook react native sdk

Comment: Yeah i know but this is just a simple fetch call that you can make from anywhere in the app like ====>>>> 
 fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/facebookUserId/invitable_friends?access_token=userToken).then(()=>{}).catch(_=>{})

Comment: ok I will try thanks!!

Comment: I have one more question..how can I get the facebookUserId ?

Comment: This is just the "facebookId" which you get in response from your "/me", that is your facebookUserId

Comment: thank it worked but, will it display others friends when others login into my app.

Comment: No, it will only display your friends which are using your app and which are not using your app both. But only list of your friends.

Comment: @AnilHitang is anything else you need to know ? i hope this is working fine :)

Comment: why taggable_friends worked instead of invitable_friends

Comment: Sadly, invitable_friends is deprecated as of April 4th 2018. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/invitable_friends/

Comment: Hey @AkshayRao, I am trying to fetch friends list, getting empty data. I am in development mode for now. Can we get friends list in development mode or we need to submit the App for review.